# KSQLDB when creating a stream the value is arriving ok in the topic associated with the stream but the key is always arriving as null

Tags: null, stream, key, ksqldb, propagation

The Message Key is not propagated, arrived messages to the sink are with Key equal to NULL the value is arriving ok what I'm doing wrong ?

Here following the implemented steps:

from a protobuf format topic:

**PRINT 'protobuf-topic';**

Key format: HOPPING(KAFKA_STRING) or TUMBLING(KAFKA_STRING) or KAFKA_STRING
Value format: PROTOBUF or KAFKA_STRING
rowtime: 2020/11/19 16:41:24.926 Z, key: [key375c71e9-4095-4ac7-8301-1b4c@4134638929333085540/-], value: content: "Hello world1" date_time: "2020-11-19T16:41:23.932842Z" id: "375c71e9-4095-4ac7-8301-1b4c9a031fed"
rowtime: 2020/11/19 16:41:26.097 Z, key: [keydeeb7023-cc02-482b-a25f-3bc7@7221912747358970420/-], value: content: "Hello world1" date_time: "2020-11-19T16:41:26.084065Z" id: "deeb7023-cc02-482b-a25f-3bc7d9caa2b4"

**CREATE STREAM protbuf_stream_source with(kafka_topic='protobuf-topic',VALUE_FORMAT='PROTOBUF');**

**CREATE STREAM protbuf_stream_stream_with_key WITH(KAFKA_TOPIC='protbuf_stream_stream_with_key_topic',VALUE_FORMAT='PROTOBUF') AS SELECT * FROM protbuf_stream_source ;**

**PRINT 'protbuf_stream_stream_with_key_topic';**

Key format: ¯_(ツ)_/¯ - no data processed
Value format: PROTOBUF or KAFKA_STRING
rowtime: 2020/11/19 16:55:34.786 Z, key: , value: CONTENT: "Hello world1" DATE_TIME: "2020-11-19T16:55:34.190391Z" ID: "65545719-a7c7-4fe6-9c9f-8802fda1de9d"
rowtime: 2020/11/19 16:55:35.888 Z, key: , value: CONTENT: "Hello world1" DATE_TIME: "2020-11-19T16:55:35.875058Z" ID: "5f796254-721d-484f-8759-2bc66f193e5a"
rowtime: 2020/11/19 16:55:36.921 Z, key: , value: CONTENT: "Hello world1" DATE_TIME: "2020-11-19T16:55:36.912333Z" ID: "4e1ea81b-09dd-43c3-8f92-eaa4725eeb17"

Answer (score 0):

The error was there from the beginning in the creation of the stream source

CREATE STREAM protbuf_stream_source with(kafka_topic='protobuf-topic',VALUE_FORMAT='PROTOBUF'); >> will create a stream with Key null

To get the Key from the topic the key must be declared in the creation command :

CREATE STREAM protbuf_stream_source(key VARCHAR KEY) with(kafka_topic='protobuf-topic',VALUE_FORMAT='PROTOBUF');